# How to get all values from JSON in c# 3.5 framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Below is my JSON response. I want to fetch `orderid`, `caseid` each filed one by one and their value.

```
"cases": [
  {
    "status": "DISMISSED",
    "createdAt": "2015-09-18T08:56:04+0000",
    "investigationId": 19246020,
    "caseId": 19246020,
    "score": 794.6295793608853,
    "adjustedScore": 794.6295793608853,
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-18T08:56:05+0000",
    "headline": "Steven Rusk",
    "orderId": "116588",
    "orderDate": "",
    "orderAmount": 425.0,
    "associatedTeam": {
      "teamName": "B2C Jewels",
      "teamId": 4289
    },
    "reviewDisposition": null,
    "uuid": "5821ed91-5f8f-4b51-bd63-a8834f2a95b3"
  },
  {
    "status": "DISMISSED",
    "createdAt": "2015-09-16T11:33:28+0000",
    "investigationId": 19114061,
    "caseId": 19114061,
    "score": 241.65405995385285,
    "adjustedScore": 241.65405995385285,
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-18T19:07:51+0000",
    "headline": "221.134.83.50",
    "orderId": "101",
    "orderDate": "2015-09-16T17:07:30+0000",
    "orderAmount": 9.99,
    "associatedTeam": {
      "teamName": "B2C Jewels",
      "teamId": 4289
    },
    "reviewDisposition": null,
    "uuid": "301f2cfc-3b67-4fc0-bf83-19099c2ea4bf"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a class named as cases and then you need to map your json to the List then you can iterate through the list hope it will work for you .

```
 List<cases> = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<cases>>(your json string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install Json.Net package from Nuget and then add this line of code in you project

```
var myList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("Your Json String..!!");
```

this should do it